# Inspect a Queue to print all elements

Tags: java, oop, queue

I am currently revising for my programming exam and I have came across a question from a past paper that has me rather confused.

I have two classes, Queue and Node, shown below.

The question states that I have to extend the behaviour of the Queue class by adding the necessary code to the inspectQueue method that prints to the console all the data stored within the queue.

The only solution I can think of, and it is very weak, is to have a simple ArrayList and every time an element is enqueued/dequeued then add/remove the node to/from the list.

Is there a better solution that I am glossing over? I'd really appreciate some guidance.

I've commented the code where I have implemented my "solution" the rest of the code is how it appears in the exam paper.

Thanks for your time.

Queue.java

```
public class Queue {

protected Node head;
protected Node last;

    //added by me
    private ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    //end my add

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (this.head == null);
}

public void enqueue(Object d) {
    Node n = new Node();
    n.setData(d);
    nodes.add(n); //added by me
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
        head = n;
        last = n;

    }
    else {
        last.setNext(n);
        last = n;
    }
}

public Object dequeue() {
    if(this.isEmpty()) {
        this.last = null;
        return null;
    }
    else {
        Node h = this.head;
                    nodes.remove(h); //added by me
        head = h.getNext();
        return h.getData();
    }

}

public Object peek() {
    if(this.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        Node t = this.head;
        return t.getData();
    }
}

public void clearQueue() {
    this.head = null;
    this.last = null;
}

public void inspectQueue() {
         //added by me (all below)
     System.out.println("Inspecting Queue: (contains " + nodes.size() + " nodes)");
     for(Node n : nodes) {
      System.out.println(n.getData());
     }
}



}
```

Node.java

```
public class Node  {

protected Object data;
protected Node next;

public void setNext(Node e) {
    this.next = e;
}

public Node getNext() {
    return this.next;
}

public void setData(Object d) {
    this.data = d;
}

public Object getData() {
    return this.data;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic data structure, called a LinkedList. In the your code for the Node class you can see the following:

```
protected Node next;
```

This means that every Node also holds a reference to the next Node in the list. If this Node is `null`, there are no more elements in the list. Knowing this, you can loop somewhat like this:

```
Node currentNode = this.head;
while(currentNode != null) {
    System.out.println(currentNode.getData().toString());
    currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
}
```

This eliminates the need for an ArrayList to store your references.
The LinkedList is a VERY frequently used data structure and very important to understand. If you have any questions, just go ahead and ask!

If you also want to have the size, keep a counter along, increment it each time you call `getNext()`, and print the size after the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and additional explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Your nodes form a linked list, so just do

```
public void inspectQueue() {
    Node n = head;
    while (n != null) {
        System.out.println(n.getData());
        n = n.getNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh. I need to do some serious research into linked lists. So obvious yet completely flummoxed me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the array, you have that information stored within the Node `next` property:

```
public void inspectQueue() {
    Node current = head;
    while(current != null) {
        System.out.println(n.getData());
        current = current.getNext();
    }
}
```

That data structure is called [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `while(current != null)` and `current.getData()`?

Comment: If the queue is empty, this will give an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solution is to start with `queue.head` and traverse the linked list of nodes using `node.next`, printing the data as you go along.